# gwt-dnd multidragging

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I am using gwt-links and gwt-dnd frameworks for making node diagrams. My problem is that i want to make dragging on multiple objects. Does somebody have experiences with this task?

Any idea or pointing to right direction helps.

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually used the gwt-links library but the getting started section gave me an outlook of the general idea. It uses gwt-dnd to move the items around so the only thing you need to do is the following:

```
PickupDragController dragController = new PickupDragController(controller.getView(), true);

// Allow multiple widgets to be selected at once using CTRL-click
dragController.setBehaviorMultipleSelection(true);

dragController.makeDraggable(labelHello);
dragController.makeDraggable(labelWorld);
// Register the dragController in gwt-links
controller.registerDragController(dragController);
```

That is, use the gwt-links as intended on the getting started wiki http://code.google.com/p/gwt-links/wiki/GettingStarted

and add the setBehaviourMultipleSelection(true); line in your dragController initialization.

Comment: Thanks Thanos, so easy. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Anytime mate. If the answer is the right one then please accept it as correct